# Spring Data Rest - Null Pointer in PersistentEntityResourceAssembler

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have an issue with @RepositoryRestResource returning a 500 error due to a null pointer.

I have an abstract class named `Resource` which is uses `InheritanceType.JOINED` and `@JsonSubTypes`  to provide about 5 subclasses of `Resource` such as `ServerResource`.  The specific `Resource` is returned fine when referenced in another entity that it joins with. The PagingAndSortingRepository also works fine when called in code.  The problem is the endpoint exposed by @RepositoryRestResource for the `Resource` entity returns a 500 error (due to NPE) when called directly.

After debugging, I found the issue is due to the line `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler:154`.  The mapping object is null because the framework could not map `ServerResource.class` to the parent `Resource.class`.  The cache is a map, and uses `.getClass()`.

Are there any ways I can get one endpoint for the `Resource` entity working for these separate types?  This almost seems like a bug.

Comment: I can POST to the URL, but GET does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correct this issue i overrode the `resourceMappings()` method, and injected the mappings I needed.  This fixed the issue, and now the /resources uri is working as intended.

```
package com.environment.config;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.type.filter.AssignableTypeFilter;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.RepositoryResourceMappings;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMappings;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMetadata;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration;

import com.environment.domain.Resource;
import com.environment.util.Tuple;

@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    public ResourceMappings resourceMappings() {
        RepositoryResourceMappings rm = RepositoryResourceMappings)super.resourceMappings();
        try {
            Field cacheField = rm.getClass().getDeclaredField("cache");
            cacheField.setAccessible(true);
            Map<Class<?>, ResourceMetadata> cache = (Map<Class<?>, ResourceMetadata>) cacheField.get(rm);

            //Get metadata for parent object
            ResourceMetadata resourceMetadata = cache.entrySet().stream()
                .map(Tuple<Class<?>,ResourceMetadata>::new)
                .filter(t -> Resource.class.equals(t.t))
                .map(t -> t.u)
                .findFirst()
                .get();

            ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
            provider.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(Resource.class));

                provider.findCandidateComponents("com/environment")
                .stream()
                .map(beanDef -> {
                    try {
                        return Class.forName(beanDef.getBeanClassName());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                })
                .filter(c -> !Resource.class.equals(c))
                .filter(c -> Resource.class.isAssignableFrom(c))
                .peek(c -> System.out.println("Mapping: " + c)
                .forEach(c -> cache.put((Class<?>) c, resourceMetadata));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return rm;
    }

}
```